# vertx HTTPS server stopped working after upgrade to 3.8.4

Tags: ssl, https, vert.x

After upgrading from 3.2.1 to 3.8.4 our vertx https server stopped working.

While the server was working fine in 3.2.1, now it logs this:

[id: 0xadd44915, L:/10.55.16.66:20001 - R:/131.216.10.22:10978] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

Discarded inbound message UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 545, cap: 574) that reached at the tail of the pipeline. Please check your pipeline configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Using latest netty jars resolved the issue.